# UglifyJs plugin started throwing error Unexpected Token

Tags: webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I use webpack to bundle the code for my electron application and use uglifyJs plugin. This was working fine till yesterday. To resolve a certain issue, I installed the node module fix-path, after which on running webpack I get the following error:

> ERROR in desktopServices.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: name
>   (IPCModule) [desktopServices.js:16956,6]

I uninstalled that node module, removed the node_modules folder and did a fresh install using npm install.

However, the error persists.

I already use babel to transpile the code so it is not because of uglify not supporting es6 features as mentioned at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2972

I searched around but I have hit a dead end as to how to fix this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution to the issue. The problem was that somehow my webpack version also got upgraded, which in itself is not a bad thing. But to get uglifyjs webpack plugin to work with my code base, I had a few weeks ago, installed the **uglifjs-webpack-plugin@beta**, which uses uglify-es and which did not throw any errors with my code.

However, this had to be installed within the webpack folder inside node_modules for it to work. I had installed it at the project level but it still threw the error but installing within webpack prevented any errors, so I just went ahead with that. I used the command from https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/78#issuecomment-314201150

```
npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@beta
```

Now, since the webpack got updated, this weird little step of installing the beta plugin had to be done again. Strangely enough, I had added this exact solution in a file called IMPORTANT_MEMO in my project but did not even look at it, probably because I did not realize that webpack had updated.